# PostgreSQL - return a record[] from a plpgsql function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, recordtype

I have an `employer` and an `employee` table. I have a join table that joins them.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employer (id int primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE employee (id int primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE employer_employee_join(
    employer_id int REFERENCES employer(id),
    employee_id int REFERENCES employee(id)
);

INSERT INTO employer (id, name) VALUES (1, 'the boss');
INSERT INTO employee (id, name) VALUES (1, 'employee1');
INSERT INTO employee (id, name) VALUES (2, 'employee2');

INSERT INTO employer_employee_join (employer_id, employee_id) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO employer_employee_join (employer_id, employee_id) VALUES(1, 2);
```

My sql query returns `employer` and aggregates `employee` returning an array of records (`record[]`).

```sql
SELECT 
employer.id, employer.name, array_agg((employee.id, employee.name))
FROM employer
LEFT JOIN employer_employee_join
ON employer_employee_join.employer_id = employer.id
LEFT JOIN employee
ON employee.id = employer_employee_join.employee_id
GROUP BY employer.id;
```

This works fine.

[image]

But when I put it in a PL/PGSQL function it fails:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _test()
    RETURNS table(id integer, name text, agg record[]) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin
    SELECT 
    employer.id, employer.name, array_agg((employee.id, employee.name))
    FROM employer
    LEFT JOIN employer_employee_join
    ON employer_employee_join.employer_id = employer.id
    LEFT JOIN employee
    ON employee.id = employer_employee_join.employee_id
    GROUP BY employer.id;
end;
$BODY$
```

The error is

```
ERROR:  PL/pgSQL functions cannot accept type record[]
SQL state: 0A000
```

How can I get a plpgsql function to return an array of records?

(I don't really want to use `json_agg()` because of another layer in the system outside of postgresql and my control)

Comment: What you really want is a [`(int, text)` tuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html), not an arbitrary `record`. In fact you already have a name for that type, so you can just write `employee[]`.

Comment: "*My sql query returns employer and aggregates employee*" - why are you doing this? "*I don't really want to use `json_agg()` because of another layer in my system*" - what is that "other layer" and how does it process postgres record arrays easier than structured and trivially parseable json?

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. `employee[]` is what I was looking for. 

But when I only want to return a subsection of a table could I return an array of tuples?

(The other layer is outside postgresql.)

Comment: If you want only a selection of columns, you'd define a custom composite type for that. See the docs I linked.

Comment: Ah, I got there in the end. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer rather than editing the question. What you did is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bergi. It was a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) I needed.

```sql
create type employee_agg as (id int, name text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _test()
    RETURNS table(id integer, name text, agg employee_agg[]) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
    return query
    SELECT 
    employer.id, 
    employer.name, 
    array_agg(row(employee.id, employee.name)::employee_agg)
    FROM employer
    LEFT JOIN employer_employee_join
    ON employer_employee_join.employer_id = employer.id
    LEFT JOIN employee
    ON employee.id = employer_employee_join.employee_id
    GROUP BY employer.id;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: don't do that... just use SQL..

Answer (score 0):

## Use a VIEW

Just do this...

```sql
CREATE VIEW _test
AS
    SELECT 
    employer.id, 
    employer.name, 
    array_agg(row(employee.id, employee.name)::employee_agg)
    FROM employer
    LEFT JOIN employer_employee_join
    ON employer_employee_join.employer_id = employer.id
    LEFT JOIN employee
    ON employee.id = employer_employee_join.employee_id
    GROUP BY employer.id;
```

Your function has no arguments, it's just a query. This is a much better idea.

Alternatively, you can use a `SQL` function (but the view is better).

Comment: It must be a function sadly.

Comment: @mmm111mmm then use SQL. It'll work the same but it'll be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  PL/pgSQL functions cannot return type record[]

Because I set `RECORD[]` type to a `RETURNS` clause as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS RECORD[] AS $$
BEGIN                          -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ 
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Actually, `RECORD[]` type doesn't exist in PostgreSQL according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969232/declaring-a-record-variable-gets-variable-has-pseudo-type-record-e#77969423) of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969232/declaring-a-record-variable-gets-variable-has-pseudo-type-record-e).